# Snowflake cross join + lateral flatten

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lateral-join

I have a semistructured column that I would like to left lateral join after a cross join.

```sql
with t as (
    select parse_json('{"1": 1, "2": 2}') as col
)

, cartesian as (
    select 1 as a union
    select 2 as a union
    select 3 as a
)

select *
from t
cross join cartesian
left join lateral flatten(input => t.col) as js
  on js.key::int = cartesian.a::int
```

In the above, I would expect the original cross join to expand the result count from 1 to 3; and the left lateral join should not reduce the number of rows returned.

The result I obtain is unexpected:

| COL | A | SEQ | KEY | PATH | INDEX | VALUE | THIS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| { "1": 1, "2": 2 } | 1 | 1 | 1 | ['1'] | NULL | 1 | { "1": 1, "2": 2 } |
| { "1": 1, "2": 2 } | 2 | 2 | 2 | ['2'] | NULL | 2 | { "1": 1, "2": 2 } |

Am I crazy, or is the `left` keyword not doing what it should here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood question correctly you are aiming for:

```
with t as (
    select parse_json('{"1": 1, "2": 2}') as col
)
, cartesian as (
    select 1 as a union
    select 2 as a union
    select 3 as a
)
select *
from cartesian 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t, TABLE(flatten(input => t.col))) as js
  ON js.key::int = cartesian.a::int;
```

Output:

[image]

Here the flattening of the JSON is perfomed inside inlined view and the result is joined using `LEFT JOIN` to tally table.

---

> *Its a small difference, but in the above is t truly cross joined to cartesian?my intention was to have col populated in all rows above; by cross joining t to `cartesian*

It could be adjusted:

```
with t as (
    select parse_json('{"1": 1, "2": 2}') as col UNION ALL
     select parse_json('{"3": 3}') as col
)

, cartesian as (
    select 1 as a union
    select 2 as a union
    select 3 as a
)

select *
from cartesian 
CROSS JOIN t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t, TABLE(flatten(input => t.col))) as js
  ON js.key::int = cartesian.a::int
 AND t.col = js.this
ORDER BY t.col, A;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Its a small difference, but in the above is `t` truly cross joined to `cartesian`? In that case wouldnt `col` be non-null in all rows of the result?

Comment: @NolanConaway I have adjusted the query to the revised requirement.

Comment: Ah that solves the immediate issue, but still unclear why the original left join does not behave like any other table join. My intuition is that this is an implementation detail of lateral views (they work like for loops according to snowflake docs), but i didn't find any caveat in the docs on this matter.

Comment: I dug up the relevant documentation: "Unlike the output of a non-lateral join, the output from a lateral join includes only the rows generated from the inline view. The rows on the left-hand side do not need to be joined to the right hand side because the rows on the left-hand side have already been taken into account by being passed into the inline view." https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html